# How to connect Data Base

Tags: oracle, shell, unix

I want to connect DB Using `Unix shell script` but i an not able to connect

below mention Code

## DB

```
export ORACLE_HOME="oracle"
value=`/oracle/bin/sqlplus -S user/pwd@SHM4EQ << EOF

SET LINESIZE 300
SET PAGESIZE 300
SET HEADING OFF

SELECT  * form dual

EOF`
```

Comment: Can you update your question and add the error message you got, please

Comment: no error message i got

Comment: ORACLE_HOME should point to a (absolute) path, not just "oracle". First try to run ". oraenv" and this will prompt you for the name (SID) of the database you want to connect to. Then run your script without the ORACLE_HOME line. If thus works you have the basic ingredients. The oraenv script sets the environment according to the SID. It is an interactive script, but can be used non-interactively by setting "ORAENV_ASK=NO", then set the ORACLE_SID value to the database name, then run ". oraenv".

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
#!/bin/bash

LogDirectory='/var/tmp/logs'
DataDirectory='/var/tmp/data'

DBUSER='scott'
DBUSERPASSWORD='tiger'
DBSID='oracle'

sqlplus -s ${DBUSER}/${DBUSERPASSWORD}@${DBSID} <<EOF
set linesize 32767
set feedback off
set heading off

select * from dual;

EOF
```